# Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node' in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I setup a bootstrap alert that is dismissible. When the user clicks on the 'x', the onClick handler fires and dispatches an action to the store. I fire the action to re-populate a grid with the initial items in the grid before the alert. The action fires successfully, alert is dismissed, and the grid is re-populated. But I keep getting this error in the console:

Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.

I have omitted styles, imports etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
class Grid extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);

  }


  handleClick() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchAllItems(items))
  }

  render() {

    const { item } = this.props.grid;

    let display;

    if (item !== "not found") {
      display = (
        item.map((item, index) => {
          const imgPath = require(`../../api/images/${item.id}.png`);
          return (
            <div key={index} className="col-xs-6 col-md-2">
              <Link style={aTagStyle} className="thumbnail">
                <img src={imgPath} style={imgStyle} />
                <p style={textStyle}>{item.url}</p>
                <p style={textStyle}>{item.name}</p>
              </Link>
            </div>
          );
        })
      );
    } else {
      display = (
        <div className="alert alert-danger center-block" role="alert" style={alertStyle}>
          <a href="#" className="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close" onClick={this.handleClick}>&times;</a>
          <strong>item Not Found, Please Try Again!</strong>
        </div>
      );      
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {display}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Bootstrap may be trying to remove the node after an animation event occurs. What is likely happening is that the action fires, the DOM is rendered without the alert, then bootstrap is trying to remove the alert from the DOM causing this error. Depending on the version of bootstrap you are using, you may be able to solve this by using the react-bootstrap library (https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#alerts)

Comment: Yes, nothing else should modify the DOM generated by React. If you want to use Bootstrap components, consider using special `react-bootstrap` library rather than original bootstrap.js code.

Comment: Did you find solution to your problem?

Comment: i had the same error while trying to update a datatable, react keeps track of the the components using the 'key' attribute, i had not set that. after adding a unique key to table elements it worked great